# asp.net Identity outside of MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, identity

I created a login system for one MVC App based on the new Identity framework, and since I already went through all the hard work of modifying my database to match the Identity 2.0 requirements, I was wondering if it would be possible to use it outside of MVC, so I could reuse what I already created, like a login system for a desktop project that I'm working on for example. If so, can I implement the login system on a .dll that can be reused on other projects?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could use your existing database for another application.  Add the ADO.NET Entity Data Model, and point it to your database.  Then, if you need to, select "Update Model from Database" and you should be all set.

Although, it may be just as easy to create your own user/roles tables.  It's frustrating (to me) that Identity creates the Primary keys as strings, even though they are essentially Guids.

Comment: but will the Identity authentification work the same outside of an MVC App? or what should I add to make it work?

Comment: Ah I see.  I haven't tried that.  I believe the identity membership is specifically for asp.net.  Why not give it a shot?  Wouldn't take too long